# Accessing the usage graph on Azure portal can it be downloaded as a graph not as csv or json

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

Is there any way I can get the cost graph of my usage from Azure portal be downloaded as a graph not as csv or json ? Is there any REST API or do you have any other suggestions for me?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your `Cost analysis` under `Cost Management`, there is a `Export` option and it supports  download it with the PNG, Excel and CSV format.

Suppose the PNG  format is what you want.

[image]